# Sending invoice from webform civicrm

Tags: webform-civicrm

Just wondering if anyone can direct me how I can configure webform and civicrm to send invoice to user when they submit the webform.

I can see from the URL (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration) that email receipt is possible using webform civicrm.

*Email receipt - if enabled, these will be sent from the webform just as they would be from the real contribution page*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you connected a contribution page to your webform? via the civicrm tab and within that the contributions tab.

If so then you need to set up the contribution page to send a receipt.

[image]

If you don't have a contribution page connected and you don't need one then you might like to consider using Webform Emails found at /node/#/webform/emails to send your emails

Comment: And if you want the 'receipt' to say 'invoice' for Pay Later contributions, then use an {if} statement in the receipt template.